# How to keep user in the game room even if activity loses focus

Tags: android, google-play-games

By default when the user closes screen player leaves the room and when it opens the screen back user logs back in. I am extending BaseGameActivity and I start quick game on onSignInSucceeded. I want to keep the user in game even if the screen is closed, received a call etc.

1 . How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

2 . Am I misconfiguring something?

3 . Is this because of the way GameHelper is written? should I reimplement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you cannot keep the game running if the Activity loses focus. This restriction is deep down in the API, not in GameHelper. We may or may not change in the future, but for now there is no way to achieve that behavior. The recommendation is calling leaveRoom() on onStop() to ensure proper cleanup.

Comment: Thanks. This is a feature request from me. Putting this as an issue on play-games-platform if there is not one.

Answer (score 0):

I remove gamehelper.onstop() in BaseGameActivity.onstop(), and it works.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try that after Bruno's answer. How do you determine if the focus losing event requires you to actually leave room.

Comment: This is undefined behavior and a bad idea. Working against the API is going to get you in trouble when it comes to production apps.

Comment: The fact that it appears to work doesn't change the fact that it's not recommended :-D That will cause resource leaks and general flakiness and may not work in future versions!