# Prevent GoogleApiClient from disconnecting on onStop()

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm developing a game using Google Play Game Services, specifically a real-time multiplayer game. Right now I'm having a problem with the suggested usage pattern of the [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) which consist of calling [disconnect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#disconnect()) during [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()), this causes the game to stop if for example a player receives a call.
A possible solution would be to use a [bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) but the problem would persist because I should call [unbindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection)).
What are the common approaches to this problem ? I searched the internet but with no results.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I used the wrong keywords doing my searches, these two links provide an exhaustive answer :

- [how-to-keep-user-in-the-game-room-even-if-activity-loses-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100169/how-to-keep-user-in-the-game-room-even-if-activity-loses-focus/19101847#19101847)
- [google-play-game-services-how-to-not-leave-room-onpause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678211/google-play-game-services-how-to-not-leave-room-onpause/18679270#18679270)